# Use Backblaze to store webapp user's private images?

Tags: backblaze

I want to use [Backblaze B2](https://www.backblaze.com/b2/cloud-storage.html) to store images for small webapp. Users can store (not share!) images in it. How can I use Backblaze so that images are kept private, but can still be accessed through their specific URLs?

One way is to download the images in the backend (using the B2 API) and then render them to the frontend, but I worry that this is too slow (before the user can see the image, it's been downloaded from B2 to the backend and from the backend to the browser).

Are there other ways of doing this?

Comment: Is your use case like unlisted videos on YouTube - you can access the image if you know the URL, or is it more like private videos, where you have to have to be authenticated and authorized?

Comment: It's the latter: you need to be authenticated and authorized to access the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your webapp is authenticating your users and knows which user is authorized to access which resources, you have to serve the content via the webapp. Backblaze doesn't have a way to decide whether to serve an image or not.